# possible to edit SSRS rdl.data file?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm sending an SSRS report as part of a support ticket.  They would also like a copy of any rdl.data files as well, since they don't have access to our database servers.  However, the data is a bit sensitive and I'd like to sanitize it a bit.  Is it possible to edit the cached rdl.data files in some way?

Comment: You are mixing up rdl files and data. RDL files are report definitions that tell you have to obtain and render data. An rdl file has no data itself. Can you be more clear please?

Answer (score 0):

The *.rdl.data files look to be binary, so probably not editable. I'd also expect the report to fail if it could not connect to the data source, regardless of whether a *.rdl.data file was present.